# Splitting an array using each_with_slice but keeping specific value(s) in resultant arrays (one liner)

Tags: arrays, ruby, slice, each

I'm hoping to get an array into a specific format and do so in a one-liner if possible. Using `each_slice(2).to_a` is helpful in splitting the array, however I would like to keep second coordinate of each array as the first coordinate of the next array.

**Initial Array**

```
# format is [x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4]...

full_line_coords = [[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]]
```

**Desired Output**

```
# desired format is [[[x1, y1], [x2, y2]], [[x2, y2], [x3, y3]], [[x3, y3], [x4, y4]]]...
desired = [[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [3, 3]], [[3, 3], [4, 4]]]
```

**Success without one-liner**

```
# without one line:

desired = []
temp_array = []

full_line_coords.each do |x|
  temp_array << x.each_slice(2).to_a
end

temp_array.each do |x|
  i = 0
  until i == x.length - 1
    desired << [x[i], x[i+1]]
    i += 1
  end
end

p desired

# => [[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [3, 3]], [[3, 3], [4, 4]], [[5, 5], [6, 6]], [[6, 6], [7, 7]], [[7, 7], [8, 8]]]
```

Unsure how to make this as one-line, found it simple enough to do the split, but not keeping the end/start coordinates in each array (as below).

**One-liner attempt**

```
attempt = full_line_coords.each { |x| p x.each_slice(2).to_a.each_slice(2).to_a } # p to show this is where i'd like the array to be in 'desired' format if possible.

# => [[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[3, 3], [4, 4]]]
#    [[[5, 5], [6, 6]], [[7, 7], [8, 8]]]
```

**Background/Reasoning**

The only reason I wish to keep it is a one-liner is because I want to return the "parent" object itself, not just the resulting attributes.

"Parent" objects being a list of links: `#<Link:0x803a2e8>`, with many attributes, including "segments".

```
links.each do |l|
  puts l.segments
end

# Gives an array of XY coordinates, including all vertices. e.g. [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

I am then looking to use the "desired" output in some other defined methods but return the link object itself at the end `#<Link:0x803a2e8>`, not just products from the link's attributes.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the first option I found:

```
full_line_coords.flat_map { |e| e.each_slice(2).each_cons(2).to_a }
```

Find the methods in [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html) class and [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html) class

Comment: That's ideal, thanks very much - hadn't come across using `each_cons` previously!

Answer (score 2):

Input

```
full_line_coords = [[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]]
```

Code

```
p full_line_coords.map { |var| var.slice_when { |x, y| x != y }
                                   .each_cons(2)
                                   .to_enum
                                   .map(&:itself) }
```

Output

```
[[[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [3, 3]], [[3, 3], [4, 4]]], [[[5, 5], [6, 6]], [[6, 6], [7, 7]], [[7, 7], [8, 8]]]]
```

Comment: Also works well, thank you! I added `flatten(1)` to get the exact array dimension, no hitches.